# In Android information does not update when sql server database update in backend

Tags: android

I update sql server table data then I run android app but this app show previous result It cannot show updated records whats the problem

Comment: this app show.... which app you are talking about?

Comment: my personal android app

Comment: I build app for status of customer and our customer address change then result show previous address whenever i uninstall app from mobile then again install it result show correctly But I want to without uninstall application my current updatiton show.